# Undefined method belongs_to usign Rails concern, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, activesupport-concern

I'm trying to extend a rails model from a gem.

Using *concern* I've been able to extend *class methods* but I cannot extend *associations*. `included do` returns `undefined method belongs_to`. I think Rails cannot load the class properly...

The *model* is in a *engine* and I'm trying to access it from my *gem*.

Here is the code:

```rb
# mygem/config/initializers/mymodel_extension.rb
require 'active_support/concern'

module MymodelExtension
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  #  included do
  #    belongs_to :another
  #  end

  class_methods do
    def swear
        return "I'm not doing it again"
    end
  end

end

class Myengine::Mymodel
    include MymodelExtension
end
```

From command line:

```rb
Myengine::Mymodel.swear
# => "I'm not doing it again"
```

If I uncomment the `included do` I get this `undefined method 'belongs_to' for Myengine::Mymodel:Class (NoMethodError)` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Myengine::Mymodel`class should inherit from [`ActiveRecord::Base`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb) to have `belongs_to` method defined.

`ActiveRecord::Base` includes bunch of modules, one of which is [`Associations`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L309), where [`belongs_to association`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb) is defined.

Comment: One question though: If I do `class Spina::PagePart < ActiveRecord::Base` am I extending the class? I just want to make sure I'm not overriding it.

Comment: @a.barbieri there's no such thing, as extending a class in Ruby. You are inheriting. Any methods defined in your class (if by ANY chance they are as well defined in `AR::Base`) would have precedence, so no worries